# Server broken after downloading 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I recently got 1.13 on my server and wanted to put the finishing touches/play test a mini game I have spent over 14 hours on. The problem is there are chunks missing like random holes. Normally this wouldn't be such a big issue, however it targeted the command blocks and the walls that surround the map (huge with intricate detail). All of my hours of hard work is gone, unless there is a way to fix it? BTW I can go through these holes.
I have an image but can't post it because it is not a link, it's a screenshot.
So is there a way to get my hours of hard work back??

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure the computer was not literally broken in halves after downloading a piece of software. That requires much more force than a few electrons in a wire have.

Comment: could have backed it up. corrupted worlds don't get too far into recovery without manual rebuilding imo

Comment: Never update a server without creating a backup, is something basic when you start managing this kind of things.

Comment: It was the first thing I did after getting 1.13 and on a server it doesn't warn you, lol, i'll just live with it and move on. I've wasted years of my life before so whats a couple days. (I'm dying inside) thanks Fabian Röling, i'll back it up next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a bug, the game will have advised you to make a backup before opening the world in 1.13. If you have done that, you can restore it.

Otherwise, if you have no backup, those chunks are gone. They just got deleted. You can't even restore them using a file restoration program, because they got overwritten by the new ones (and aren't complete files themselves anyway).

Moral of the story: Always make backups! 1.13 was released in a [horrible state](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702) sadly, so probably many people suffered a similar fate as yours.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide details of the bug you are referencing here, so that it's clear why you are sure the data is deleted and thus unrecoverable... (even deleted data can be recovered with the right tools, depending on the situation)

Comment: The bug was just the message "are you sure you want to play in this snapshot", even though that version wasn't called a snapshot. I don't know what caused the chunks to be deleted, but there were so many bugs in 1.13.0 that I'm not too surprised if there was one that randomly reset chunks. I don't know its report number. And the reason that the data can't be recovered is that chunks are grouped 32x32 into one file, so a single reset chunk is not like a regular deleted file that you can restore, it's a part of a file, so resetting it is just a file modification. That's why you can't recover it.

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-134411 is the bug for the snapshot/not a snapshot issue... but that bug isn't related to the issue the OP experienced. I agree the issue reported by the OP is caused by a bug, but i'd personally suggest not to be definite that it was a bug unless you can provide details... otherwise it's not that helpful to the OP.

Comment: What are you unsure about being a bug? The message? It wasn't a snapshot, the report was confirmed by a helper and the issue fixed in 1.13.1. Or the chunk reset? Data loss is always a bug, except if you press the "delete world" button or delete the file in the file manager.

Comment: removed comments to prevent confusing OP.