# How to install mods on minecraft pc 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do you put and add mods in 1.13,
I don’t know how please help.

Answer (score 2):

I hope your question wasn't meant as "how do I install mods" in general, because that can easily be figured out using Google. Instead, I'll answer specifically for 1.13:

[Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/) isn't released for 1.13 yet, so there won't be any forge mods anytime soon. I also heard that they're planning a big rewrite, so it will take quite some time before it gets released.

But some other ways of installing mods are available already:

- [Optifine](https://www.topminecraftmods.com/optifine/) can be installed directly.
- Bukkit and Spigot are available [here](https://getbukkit.org/).

No matter if these downloads say that they're beta, experimental, etc. or not, they should be treated as such, mainly because 1.13 itself isn't even completely functional yet (more information in [my other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702)).

Some things that also don't work yet:

- [Sponge](https://www.spongepowered.org/downloads/) isn't released for 1.13 yet.
- [Liteloader](http://www.liteloader.com/) isn't released for 1.13 yet.

---

**Update 2019-04-28**: Forge is now out for 1.13.2, Optifine and Bukkit are out for 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.2 and 1.14.0, Sponge and Liteloader are not out for 1.13 yet.

Comment: If someone knows something about Paper, BungeeCord, Waterfall, Canary and Neptune, which are apparently all also mod loaders, please add it here. I don't know these programs and their websites are either hard to find or not especially clear for what version they are.

Comment: Paper and Waterfall seem to have updated to 1.16.1 (this might be wrong, but as far as I can tell, they've updated recently: https://papermc.io/downloads#Paper-1.16).