# Mobs won’t spawn in mob spawner in the sky, but they do spawn on sea level

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I’m playing on the newest snapshot and I’ve made a mob spawnner higher than y150 in the ocean and mobs aren’t spawning, but they are spawning on the sea level where I made a small platform. Anyone know why?

Comment: Which type of spawner?

Comment: I can't reproduce with zombie spawners. You'll have to give more details.

Comment: It's a simple mob spawner where the mobs fall into water and drop 24 blocks. It dosen't have any spawners it's a normal spawner. Its this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OfLA3kVJhw 
I made it at about Y-150 above sea and nothing is spawning. But the mobs are spawning on sea level, not in the spawner. So I don't know what is going on. Im on a multiplayer server i only play with one more person.

Comment: I can reproduce. Seems like regular Overworld mob spawning doesn't happen at height 57+.

Comment: Actually, no, in a new world it works.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? I need xp sand loot what other spawner will work?

Comment: We researched it more in the meantime and this bug report came out of it: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-138337 I guess I'll make that an answer here.

Comment: So what do I do? Do I have to make it somewhere where there is no land and just ocean for miles? What do I do?

Comment: Build it underground. This makes the spawn rates worse, except if you light up all the caves and surfaces around it. This is not a good situation, that's why I recommended staying on 1.12.2 ever since I saw it coming that 1.13.0 would be a mess. And my point still stands, they claimed in two of the three 1.14 snapshots to have increased performance, but it's still basically as bad as in 1.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 18w43c and possibly some earlier versions: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-138337

Mobs don't spawn above the highest block that was naturally generated with the world. I don't know why this happens, this is a really weird bug. Some people started analysing the code a bit, but it'll likely take a while until it's properly figured out.

For now I would recommend to stay on 1.12.2, it's the best performing and least buggy version. For more details and reasons, see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702).

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if it matters if you're on a multiplayer world but my friend has a single player world on 18w43c and he made the same spawner in the sky and it seems to work. Maybe it's because of the world difference? Or the bug just randomly happens.