# Tp From Relative Position to Another Relative Position

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Forgive me if this was already answered, but I couldn't find a similar question.

In 1.12.2 I'd like to teleport a player from (relative position to command block) to (another relative position to command block), set to "repeating" and "always active". The solution for absolute coordinates is:

```
/execute @a[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=d] ~ ~ ~ tp @a e f g
```

I'm rather surprised, since I'd think the general case of relative source and relative destination would be asked more frequently. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is in a command block? Why do you need relative coordinates then? Do you clone the command block to different places?

Comment: Yes I'd like to clone it several times. It will also be part of a schematic, such that if I decide to move it somewhere else the command will remain relative to the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.12

This is actually a surprisingly hard thing to do with 1.12 commands. The only way I found is with a marker entity, the command inside the command block is then:

```
summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["teleportMarker"],NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Invisible:1,Marker:1}
```

Execute this command inside the command block only once per block. How you do that depends on your system.

Then tag everybody in your first area:

```
/execute @e[tag=teleportMarker] ~123 ~456 ~789 scoreboard players tag @a[r=42] add toTeleport
```

Then teleport them to the second area:

```
/tp @a[tag=toTeleport] ~987 ~654 ~321
```

Then clean up:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=toTeleport] remove toTeleport
```

And when you're done teleporting people around, you can kill the marker amour stands again:

```
/kill @e[tag=teleportMarker]
```

Killing only one of the markers works best with whatever you use to place/activate the command blocks, since that already knows the coordinates of that command block and therefore also of the armour stand.

---

## 1.13

In 1.13 you don't need a marker entity, since there is now `/execute positioned`. So you can just put

```
execute positioned ~123 ~456 ~789 run tag @a[distance=..42] add toTeleport
```

into the command block instead of summoning an entity and then executing from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it out, and it does work, but it seems what it's testing is if the radius encompasses the first coordinates, then it teleports. i.e. if ~-5 ~ ~ are the first coordinates and if r>=5, it doesn't matter if people are standing on the specific coordinates, they will be teleported from anywhere. Ideally I'd only like people standing on the coordinates to be teleported.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. You can select only one block of range with `r=1`. Everybody inside will be selected.

Comment: That's what I originally thought too, but I think the radius is relative to the command block, not relative to the relative coordinates. I'm just reporting what I found from testing lol.

Comment: It shouldn't. That's one of the main purposes of `/execute`.

Comment: You can try it if you don't believe me. I first tried ~-5 ~ ~ with r=1 and it didn't work, but for some reason r>=5 does.

Comment: `r>=5` isn't even a Minecraft syntax.

Comment: I don't mean >= literally, just any value of 5 or greater...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm totally used to the 1.13 `/execute`! In 1.12, the target selector also shifts the command execution. So you actually need an entity inside the command block. I'll update my answer. Also, it had nothing to do with the size of that radius, I don't know what happened there for you.

Comment: It's ok I understand, thank you again for the help.

Comment: It worked wonderfully in 1.12! Also didn't realize they made coords so much easier to use in 1.13.

Comment: Many things got much easier in 1.13. Too bad that its performance is so incredibly bad and it's so buggy that it's pretty much [unusable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702).