# Testfor trigger isn't working as expected in command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have made a trigger objective:

> scoreboard objectives add Test trigger

I have setup 3 command blocks with this in each one of them:

> Command Block A - `testfor @a[score_Test_min=1]`
>
> Command Block B - `testfor @a[score_Test_min=2]`
>
> Command Block C - `testfor @a[score_Test_min=3]`

and each and every one of them has a comparator to test output.

And yes I have `scoreboard players enable @a Test` in repeat.

Now the problem is that it's not working as expected of _min.

(I'm going to say light up a lot meaning the comparator will activate)

When I run the command `trigger Test set 1` it lights up the comparator for Command Block A but when I run `trigger Test set 2`, it keeps A light up, and then lights up B. I would expect A to not light up since I have a _min. This goes to same when I set the trigger to 3, then lights up all of them.

Now supposedly someone will say that just add score_Test_max but I did for all of them and what just happened is that, it doesn't light up at all. So it would be like this:

> testfor @a[score_Test_min=1,score_Test_max=1]

and when I set the objective to 1, it doesn't light up the comparator.

So is this just a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Any particular reason for using an old version?  These selectors were revamped in 1.13 to make them a bit more user friendly (in addition to removing `testfor`, which is mostly useless to begin with).

Comment: @MBraedley I am using this for my server which has Pixelmon Generations and it only has a 1.12.2 version of the mod, Im using triggers for some server management.

Comment: @MBraedley testfor, testforblock and testforblocks have been merged with execute, making them even more efficient, especially because you can now make them conditional much more easily. Testfor is now /execute if entity or /execute unless entity, testforblock is now /execute if block or /execute unless block and testforblocks is now /execute if blocks or /execute if blocks.

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Yes, I know, which is why I said it was removed and mostly useless.

Comment: @MBraedley My bad, I thought you were talking about the useless removal of testfor :P

Comment: @MBraedley Yes, there are [a lot of very good reasons to stay in 1.12.2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"score_Test_max=" is a synax error. Just use "score_Text="

```
testfor @a[score_Test_min=1,score_Test=1]
```