# Minecraft 1.13.2 crashing whenever I load a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I only just recently had this issue, but whenever I load a world in the latest release, my game crashes. For reference: I have only been able to play the game the day before the crashes occurred.

Here is the crash log:

```
[17:23:09] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Mariosupermouse
[17:23:10] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[17:23:10] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 3.1.6 build 14
[17:23:11] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[17:23:11] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[17:23:12] [Thread-2/INFO]: Initializing No Sound
[17:23:12] [Thread-2/INFO]: (Silent Mode)
[17:23:12] [Thread-2/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[17:23:12] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Preloading sound minecraft:sounds/ambient/underwater/underwater_ambience.ogg
[17:23:12] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[17:23:15] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[17:23:17] [Client thread/INFO]: Narrator library for x64 successfully loaded
[17:23:20] [Client thread/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[17:23:20] [Client thread/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
```

Is there any way I can fix this issue? I have already tried re-installing Java 8, if that helps at all.

Edit: Here is the exact error that pops up when the game crashes:

```
Java(TM) Platform SE binary is not responding
```

Comment: Can you please attach `%appdata%/.minecraft/logs/latest.log` instead? It's easier to read and often has better details. Also, does the same happen to you in 1.12.2? 1.13.x is [pretty bad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702).

Comment: @FabianRöling Thanks for the reply. I have changed the log to use the one at the address you requested. I also tried using 1.12.2 and I have the same issue. I hope the better log helps

Comment: Hm, so far this doesn't say much, except that the program froze. Were you previously able to play Minecraft without lag etc. on that device?

Comment: @FabianRöling It was a new pc but I had been playing the game for around a week before it froze and never started working. I cant run earilier versions and i have re-installed both Java and minecraft (making sure to delete files in %appdata% so it is a complete wipe) I did use commands in the minecraft world I played on (/tp) and I have read the commands are buggy on 1.13 but I didn't think it would completely brick my game. The game used to run just fine, only had occasional frame drops when loading lots of chunks.

Comment: I changed "For reference I have been able to play the game before only the day before the crashes occour" to "For reference: I have only been able to play the game the day before the crashes occurred": I am not sure if that is exactly what you meant, though.

Answer (score 0):

After many different attempts I have found a way to get my game to launch again.
Here is the process I did:

1. Completely uninstall and re-install Java
2. Completely uninstall minecraft and re-install it
   (You can create a copy of existing worlds by taking them from `AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves`)
3. Running a full scan of my computer to rid  it of any malware and broken files

After I did this the game properly loaded and the existing worlds I had run properly with no noticeable corruption.
It is likely the problem was due to a broken file in the launcher that stopped the game from loading properly though I cannot say for certain but my method did work in getting it to function normally.