# testfor wont recognize what its supposed to

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in 1.12.2.

And here's the command I'm trying to do:

```
testfor THE_ELEMENT_KING {inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}
```

But even when I have a diamond in my inventory it says I didn't match the data.

Comment: First of all, even in 1.12.2, you really don't want to be using `testfor`.  All you can do is allow a conditional command block to run, which is sometimes enough, but more often you want to do something more than just run another command.  Second, `testfor` can't really do what you want anyway.  Surprisingly, you probably want to use the `clear` command.

Comment: Also, if you're able to move to 1.13 or later (you haven't said why you're on 1.12), this becomes orders of magnitude easier to do.

Comment: @MBraedley That depends heavily on what they're trying to do.  In general, I [don't recommend updating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702) yet.

Answer (score 0):

"inventory" is a synax error. It is supposed to be capitalized.

This should be a working /testfor command:

```
/testfor THE_ELEMENT_KING {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}
```