# Resume redstone signal transfer as chunks load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Considering that vanilla methods of chunkloading since 1.13 got between impossible and very cumbersome, I'd like a more 'poor man's' method to transfer a signal:

I want redstone signal to reach the distant destination before the player does. E.g. I flick a lever at a 'control center', then fly on Elytra along the wire to a distant farm (say, 100 chunks away) that is started by that lever; and I want it to start as soon as possible after its chunks load.

Normally, the redstone signal stops at the border between loaded and unloaded chunks and freezes there - after loading subsequent chunks it won't resume, redstone on one side lit, on the other unlit, until the blocks at the old border receive an update. I wonder what sort of contraptions along the line would make it resume automatically - e.g. some sort of clocks that would automatically update the connections on chunk borders, or 'resend if not acknowledged' repeater devices so that as soon as farther segments of the line load, the signal could resume.

Was anything like that invented?

Comment: I take it to mean you want to do this without commands, which IIRC can force chunks to be loaded?

Comment: @MBraedley: Yes. Moreover I don't want to influence the chunk loading process by any means other than vicinity of a player. I want the signal to resume travel as more chunks load, not to cause more chunks to load by other means than just player flying there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue, but I would suggest a series of clocks, each within the range of the previous, that would be enabled by your redstone line of choice being turned on, and disabled when it was off. These would have a redstone line traversing into the unloaded chunks, where it would trigger a piston pushing a redstone block into the circuit. Once activated by the redstone block, those lines would continue to be active and activate further clocks along the line.

Although this method will only work once the previously unloaded chunk is loaded, it should update the redstone afterwards, provided that it is powering a section of the redstone that overlaps with the previous powering.

Another suggestion is just to cave to the option of the nether portal chunk loader, shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wDbNpKZIIM). It may not be low tech, but it works in most circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

## You can't.

Remote chunk loading is entirely broken in 1.13+, it's one of the main reasons why I [don't recommend updating beyond 1.12.2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334693/update-existing-minecraft-java-world-to-1-13-what-to-expect/334702#334702). My bug report about it is [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147818), sadly it gets mostly ignored by Mojang. You can try voting for it, but I don't have much hope that it will be fixed soon.

Comment: What do you mean? Upon arrival of a player chunks in 1.13 load just fine and most contraptions fully contained within a chunk resume from when they stopped when unloaded just fine. I'm not asking about remote chunkloaders, I'm asking about updating the redstone line as its loaded by presence of a player.

Comment: That's exactly the point: if it's contained within a chunk, it sort of works, but only if a player is nearby. As soon as something crosses a chunk border, it can and likely will break when the player leaves or comes back.

Comment: ...and I think a contraption that at its core is contained within a chunk, but can influence the chunk border to repair/restore the connection should be possible. I can think of a fairly complex version: a device that takes slow clock input = 0, fast clock input = 1, constant 0 input and constant 1 input = hold previous state; stores the state in memory and outputs slow/fast clock output depending on memorized state. Using these as repeaters less than chunkloading distance apart should work.

Comment: ...but I hope there may be an easier way, e.g. triggering block updates on chunk borders.

Comment: Apparently I never responded to your last comments here: No, remote chunk loading is absolutely impossible in 1.14+, except by continuously dropping items back and forth between portals. And I'm pretty sure even that breaks when reopening a Survival world or restarting a server.

Comment: Still not what I meant. A line of redstone dust with repeaters runs 1000 blocks north out from player position. Player flicks the lever, starting the line - the line is powered some 160 blocks through loaded chunks then there's a point where the power stops. Player starts moving along the line, and chunks load. The power *could* continue now, into the newly loaded chunks but it still won't. Break the last powered dust and replace it and you'll have another 160 blocks worth of powered line. But how to do it automatically?

Comment: Nope, as I said, completely broken. Two chunks farther than the render distance the block updates seem to somewhat queue up, beyond that they just stop entirely. So if you send a pulse through a long redstone line, it just never arrives at the other end, no matter what you load in the meantime.

Comment: Actually, just tested in 1.15.2, and the line doesn't even need any updating, it just proceeds into newly loaded chunks as they are loaded.

Comment: Apparently it's a bit different in 1.15.2 than it was in 1.14, but it's still broken, you simply cannot possibly transmit signals reliably to far distances: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HU4DsxURtYeS81oj1ecxYRhfoHBN-lq9 Maybe you were in the spawn chunks? I made that mistake often when trying to reproduce the bug.

Comment: You switched the signal off before starting moving, so apparently the game kept the two events scheduled for distribution. If you just switch it on and leave it on, it follows your travel just fine.

Comment: Sure, but that breaks most machinery on chunk borders, because absolutely all timings get messed up when something goes into unloaded chunks and some updates just get skipped entirely.