# How to clone a structure with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a house, and tried to clone the whole house somewhere like 511 blocks away. I made the house inside a red line to make the cloning process easier. But as soon as I pasted the coordinates to the place where I want the clone of the house in, it says "That position is not loaded". I don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my /fill command output "That position is not loaded"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353906/why-does-my-fill-command-output-that-position-is-not-loaded)

Answer (score -1):

Type the command `/give @p structure_block`

Comment: Hello @Freddyfuzfan! Just to help you write better answers: We usually prefer that when you write something, you also give a quick explanation of how it is the right answer, especially when its a command line. Explaining what every component does in that line could help making a better answer. See you around!

Comment: It's also not clear how structure blocks solve this problem; could you go into more detail please?