# How do I clone something to the coordinates of a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map that if you trow an item on the ground, a pillar will spawn there. But I don't know how to make the pillar spawn there. I don't know if this is even possible with the `/clone` command.

Answer (score 2):

`/execute at @e[type=item,nbt={OnGround:1b}] run clone [pillar corner xyz] [pillar opposite corner xyz] ~ ~ ~`

and then on a chain conditional command block,

`/kill @e[type=item,nbt={OnGround:1b}]`

This will spawn a pillar on any item that you drop and then delete the item. I'm sure you want to be more specific with what items to spawn pillars at, but you haven't specified, so do as you will.

Comment: I am making this is 1.12.2, for what version is this command? (And i already have the detector for the item drop)

Comment: The syntax of the /execute command was branched out in 1.13, so this solution will not work. Mind me asking why you're on 1.12.2?

Comment: I am on 1.12.2 because I am more familiar with the commands in 1.12.2

Comment: Relative coordinates are a pretty basic feature of commands. If you didn't know about that until now, I would recommend a commands tutorial anyway, and then you might as well watch/read/… one for 1.13+. But be aware of potential issues in 1.13+: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334702/171580

Comment: Also, you should have mentioned in the question that you're playing in 1.12.2. Now you can't do it anymore without invalidating the answer, which you should not do.